# Query on 250 million records

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table with below structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ColumnValues](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OutputArea] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ColumnValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ColumnValues]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ColumnValues_dbo.CensusColumns_ColumnId] FOREIGN KEY([ColumnId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CensusColumns] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ColumnValues] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ColumnValues_dbo.CensusColumns_ColumnId]
GO
```

It contains almost 250 Million records. I need to filter records based on list of OutputArea codes and ColumnIds and the query which I used is like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[OutputArea] AS [OutputArea], 
[Extent1].[ColumnId] AS [ColumnId], 
[Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[ColumnValues] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[OutputArea] IN (N'E00139237', N'E00139238', N'E00139239', N'E00139255', N'E00139257', N'E00139258', N'E00139259', N'E00139260', N'E00139261', N'E00139262', N'E00139263', N'E00139264', N'E00139265', N'E00139266', N'E00139267', N'E00139268', N'E00139689', N'E00139690', N'E00139691', N'E00139694', N'E00139814', N'E00139815', N'E00139816', N'E00139817', N'E00139818', N'E00139835', N'E00139837', N'E00139838', N'E00139847', N'E00139848', N'E00139849', N'E00139850', N'E00139855', N'E00139856', N'E00139857', N'E00139858', N'E00139939', N'E00139940', N'E00139941', N'E00139980', N'E00139981', N'E00139982', N'E00140008', N'E00140010', N'E00140011', N'E00140012', N'E00140013', N'E00140014', N'E00140015', N'E00140016', N'E00140017', N'E00140018', N'E00140019', N'E00140020', N'E00140021', N'E00140022', N'E00140023')) AND ([Extent1].[OutputArea] IS NOT NULL)
AND ([Extent1].[ColumnId] IN (298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309))
```

When I have small list of entries like less than 50 members for input the query works fine, not with great performance though. But when I run a query on an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 which is hosted on a powerful server which has 128 GB memory it mostly fails to execute and I get below error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

Is it very complex query? because I expect this to execute fast and without problem due to powerful resources on the server. 
How do I fix the problem and increase the performance?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but does OutputArea really have to be nvarchar(max)? At least the example data looks completely different.

Comment: @JamesZ No, it doesn't have to. it has 9 characters at most. I will apply it but not sure if it fix the problem.

Comment: Also having index on OutputArea maybe with OutputArea, depending on selectivity of the data and your query should help the performance and might help in query plan creation too.

Comment: Putting your Extent1.OutputArea values for the IN clause into a temp table, then use that that as your IN clause could help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, the issue is caused by the very long IN lists. Instead of using the IN list, create a temporary table with the values you want to filter on. Then rewrite the query as a join:

```
CREATE TABLE #FilterOutputArea (...) 
INSERT #FilterOutputArea VALUES ('E00139237')
... etc...

CREATE TABLE #FilterColumnID ()
INSERT #ColumnID VALUES (298)
... etc...

SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[OutputArea] AS [OutputArea], 
[Extent1].[ColumnId] AS [ColumnId], 
[Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[ColumnValues] AS [Extent1]
JOIN #FilterOutputArea ON ...
JOIN #ColumnID ON ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working perfect. Do you believe adding index on OutputArea in temp table is necessary?

Comment: Not "necessary" from a functionality perspective. But it might help performance. It depends on how large a % of OutputArea the filter selects. If the query picks more than 30% of the total data in the table, it is not worth adding an index.

Comment: @Thomas Kejser, Is there any performance degradation occurring when we use temporary tables. Or otherwise we can use common type expression or table variable because if use temporary tables then temp db usage will be more. Is it correct?